# Stored Procedure using Dapper in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dapper

I am trying to do CRUD operation in MVC using Dapper and stored procedure but I am not able to return result from model to controller due to conversion error which I am not able to solve. Please can anyone help what should I return as my result

This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult AllMobileList()
 {
     MobileMain MM = new MobileMain();
     return View(MM.AllMobileListing().ToList());
 }

 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Edit(string MobileID)   
 {
     MobileMain MM = new MobileMain();
     return View(MM.GetMobileList(MobileID));
 }
```

Model

```
public IEnumerable<TBMobileDetails> AllMobileListing()
{
    var para = new DynamicParameters();
    para.Add("@Type", 1);
    var result= con.Execute("Sp_MVCDapper", para, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToString();

    return result;  // Error happens here
}

public TBMobileDetails GetMobileList(string MobileId)
{
    var para = new DynamicParameters();
    para.Add("@Type", 2);
    para.Add("@MobileId",Convert.ToInt32(MobileId));
    var result = con.Execute("Sp_MVCDapper", para, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToString();

    return result;  // Error happens here
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

I know its a very common error and I am doing some stupid mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use Dapper's `Query<T>` extension method to get the results of a stored procedure call - if the SP uses a select statement to return data.

`Query<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can simply use for `IEnumerable<TBMobileDetails> AllMobileListing():`

```
return con.Query<TBMobileDetails>(
    "Sp_MVCDapper", para, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```

and for `TBMobileDetails GetMobileList(string MobileId)`

```
var list = con.Query<TBMobileDetails >(
    "Sp_MVCDapper", para, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

return list.Single(); // assuming that the SP only returns a single item
```

---

And as a remark: if your parameter is a number then don't use a `string` type. It only causes headaches later.

Comment: Thanks alot.. My error is solved and its working perfect